# How to connect a nokia phone in ubuntu to backup contacts?

Tags: 13.10, contacts, nokia

I wanted to backup and copy all contacts in my phone to ubuntu.Is there any software like nokia pc suite in ubuntu for this or is there any other method for back up of contacts

Answer (score 4):

You can try Wammu.

Wammu is a program to manage data in your cell phone such as contacts, calendar or messages. It is built on Gammu library, which provides abstraction layer to work with different cell phones from different vendors (including Nokia, Sony-Ericsson, Motorola, Samsung, Siemens, Huawei and others).<sup>[Wammu](http://wammu.eu/)</sup>

To download, and more info see the [website](http://wammu.eu/).  For a list of supported phones, see the [Gammu Phone Database](http://wammu.eu/phones/)